# Error opening illustrator file with Applescript

Tags: applescript, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to open and save an illustrator file based on its folder structure, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
error "Adobe Illustrator got an error: an Illustrator error occurred: -54 (' ˇˇˇ')" number 1200
```

Along with the message:

```
 Illustrator couldn't open this file as it may be locked or in use
```

Well its not locked because I can open it manually, and it definitely wasn't in use at the time.
Below is my code, please help if you can :)

```
 set inputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder"
 tell application "Finder" to set jobNumber to name of inputFolder
 set aiPath to inputFolder & "Assembly:" & jobNumber & ".ai" --path of outlined file
 set olPath to inputFolder & "Deliverables:" & jobNumber & "_OL.ai" --path of outlined file

tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
activate
open aiPath without dialogs

convert to paths (every text frame of current document) --convert text to paths
save current document in file olPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save an outlined copy to Deliverables with name + _OL.ai 

end tell
```

*******edit********

I attempted to fix it by adding the text to the alias while it was a string, and then converting it to an alias.

For some reason this works with the 1st path, but when it reaches the second it says "cannot make alias into type alias"
I am very confused, please help :/

```
 set inputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder"
 tell application "Finder" to set jobNumber to name of inputFolder
 set temp to inputFolder & "Assembly:" & jobNumber & ".ai" as string --path of outlined file
 set aiPath to temp as alias
 set temp to inputFolder & "Deliverables:" & jobNumber & "_OL.ai" --path of outlined file
 set olPath to temp as alias

 tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
activate
open file aiPath without dialogs

convert to paths (every text frame of current document) --convert text to paths
save current document in file olPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save an outlined copy to Deliverables with name + _OL.ai 

   end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable "inputFolder" is an alias and they don't normally like having text added to them. Try making it a string. Try this:

```
 set inputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder"
 set inputFolder to inputFolder as string
 tell application "Finder" to set jobNumber to name of folder inputFolder
 set aiPath to inputFolder & "Assembly:" & jobNumber & ".ai" --path of outlined file
 set olPath to inputFolder & "Deliverables:" & jobNumber & "_OL.ai" --path of outlined file

tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
activate
open aiPath without dialogs

convert to paths (every text frame of current document) --convert text to paths
save current document in file olPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save an outlined copy to Deliverables with name + _OL.ai 

end tell
```

**Update**

Check your file path for "olPath" exists. AI will not make new folder from what I am remembering. If I take your save command and change it to save on my desktop it works fine.

```
set FilePath to ((path to desktop) as string) & "TestFile.ai"
tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
    activate
    save current document in file FilePath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save an outlined copy to Deliverables with name + _OL.ai 

end tell
```

**Update 2**

This works for me.

```
set inputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder"
set inputFolder to inputFolder as string
tell application "Finder" to set jobNumber to name of folder inputFolder
set aiPath to inputFolder & "Assembly:" & jobNumber & ".ai" --path of outlined file
set olPath to inputFolder & "Deliverables:" & jobNumber & "_OL.ai" --path of outlined file

tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
    activate
    open file aiPath without dialogs

    convert to paths (every text frame of current document) --convert text to paths
    save current document in file olPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save an outlined copy to Deliverables with name + _OL.ai 

end tell
```

Comment: I tried your code but when the variable aiPath is a string illustrator can't open it and gets a parameter error

Comment: throw the word "file" after  "open"

Comment: That did the trick, it opens up now, but for some reason it has a problem when saving. It comes up with the error: "The file may be read only, or another user may have it open. Please save the document with a different name or in a different folder"

Comment: I see what your getting at, but I just want to do a save as to save it as the OL path. I've done this before on a previous question and it worked after you helped me on it.

Comment: That is the folder exists but the OL file doesn't

Comment: So inputFolder & "Deliverables:" is a vaild destination folder and does exists? There has to be an issue with the folders. Making the variables "aiPath" and "olPath" works the way I expected and the saving is perfect.

Comment: I just made a folder name "56325" with two folders inside "Assembly" and "Deliverables". I placed a file named "56325.ai" inside Assembly and ran the script selecting folder "56325". It opened and saved an outlined version in folder Delieverales as "56325_ol.ai". Make sure your destination folder exists. Also on a side note, weird things can happen if you are running the script on a server folder.

Comment: I tried it your way round with a fake folder and it worked, but it still wont work for the real thing even when its not on the server. I triple checked the folders were there and correctly named, so the only thing I can think of that is different is that the real thing was pulled off a server. Very strange, but at least your script definitely works :P